# Evaluate $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\frac{-xy}{x^2 + y^2}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

> Evaluate the following limit: $$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\frac{-xy}{x^2 + y^2}$$

---

**My try:**

Using polar substitution - putting $x =r\cos(\theta)$, $y = r\sin(\theta)$,

$$\implies\lim_{r \to 0} \frac{-r^2\cos(\theta) \sin(\theta)}{r^2(\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta)} =\lim_{r \to 0} -\cos(\theta) \sin(\theta) = -\cos(\theta) \sin(\theta)$$

Does this make any sense?

Also, approaching from two different sides,
$$\begin{align}\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\frac{-xy}{x^2 + y^2} & = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{-x(0)}{x^2 + (0)^2} = 0\\\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\frac{-xy}{x^2 + y^2} & = \lim_{y\to 0}\frac{-(0)y}{(0)^2 + y^2} = 0 \end{align}$$

Both are equal... but the limit doesn't exist which I verified from [Symbolab](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/step-by-step/%5Clim_%7B%5Cleft(x%2C%20y%5Cright)%5Cto%5Cleft(0%2C%200%5Cright)%7D%5Cleft(-%5Cfrac%7Bxy%7D%7Bx%5E%7B2%7D%2By%5E%7B2%7D%7D%5Cright)?or=input). What should I do to evaluate this?

Comment: You cancel the $r^2$ so the limit depends essentially on your angle. Wouldn't that indicate that the limit does not exist? Just to be clear: You can use polar coordinates to prove that the limit does NOT exist. You cannot use polars to prove that the limit exist.

Comment: What happens if you approach to the origin along the line $y=x$?

Comment: Well, there can be only one limit, and $\theta$ can change. $\cos\theta\sin\theta$ is a “directional limit.” But $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}$ doesn’t specify a direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $y=ax$. Then
$$
\lim_{x\to0}f(x,ax)=\frac{-a}{1+a^2}
$$
and certainly depends on $a$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $(x, y) = (\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n})$ as $n \to \infty$. In that case, your limit evaluates to $-\frac{1}{2}$, which is a contradiction with the other two limits you found so the limit doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

Using polar coordinates you find that $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{-xy}{x^{2}+y^{2}}=\lim_{r\to 0;r>0}\frac{-r^{2}\cos \theta\sin \theta}{r^{2}}=-\cos\theta\sin\theta, \quad (*)$$
So the limit doesn't exists, it depends of values for $\theta$ , just take $\theta=\pi$ and we have $0$ as limit but $\theta=\pi/6$ we have $-\sqrt{3}/4$ as limit, contradiction. I think it's perfectly valid argument. If you need use path, just see in the path $r(t)=(t,mt)$ with $m\in \mathbb{R}^{*}$.

**EDIT:**

As pointed out Hans Lundmark in the comment, the line in $(*)$ has problems about rigor mathematics. We will try to fix with change of variables to polar coordinates we have for $x^{2}+y^{2}\not=0$, that,
$$\frac{-xy}{x^{2}+y^{2}}=-\frac{r^{2}\cos\theta\sin\theta}{r^{2}}=-\cos\theta\sin\theta, \quad r>0$$
and since for different values of $\theta$ we get differents values so the $\displaystyle \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{-xy}{x^{2}+y^{2}}$ doesn't exists.

Comment: The argument is valid, but it shouldn't be written that way. The first equals sign that you have written is false, since the left-hand side doesn't exist, while the right-hand side does, if you interpret it as a one-variable limit in $r$ for a fixed value of $\theta$, which is precisely what you do when you write your second equals sign.

Comment: Hi @HansLundmark thank you for the feedback and I understand your remark. Can you show how I should write it, formally? Maybe as like: Change of variables to polar coordinates give $\frac{-xy}{x^{2}+y^{2}}=-\cos\theta\sin \theta$ and then fix $\theta$ for some values? I understand the problem is in left-hand the limit doesn't exists but right-hand the limit exists so not matching.

Comment: Yes, that's much better. Write it like that, and then say something like “since we get different values for different $\theta$, the two-variable limit doesn't exist”.

Comment: @HansLundmark I edited, what do you think now? Thanks for you feedback.

Comment: It still looks weird to me, since you write that something (which actually doesn't exist, but we don't know that yet) is simultaneously equal to $0$ and to $-\sqrt{3}/4$. I would avoid using the notation $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}$ at all, until after the limit has been shown to exist (or not).

Comment: Hi @HansLundmark I fixed it again, now is it more rigorous?

Comment: Now it looks fine!

Comment: Thank you very much, I have learned a lot from your corrections @HansLundmark !